# C# Multiple bools in one if statement

Tags: c#

I have an `if` statement that currently uses the bool "debug".

It looks like this:

```
for (; ; )
{
    if (debug)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please type in a command");
        cmd = Console.ReadLine();
        p.Send(cmd);
        Console.WriteLine("Command successfully executed\n");
        if (cmd == "switch")
        {
            debug = !debug;
        }
        else if (cmd == "night")
        {
            p.Send(night);
        }
        else if (cmd == "fps 300")
        {
            p.Send(threefps);
        }
        else if (cmd == "fps 600")
        {
            p.Send(sixfps);
        }
        else if (cmd == "fps max")
        {
            p.Send(maxfps);
        }
        else if (cmd == "quality")
        {
            p.Send(quality);
        }
        else if (cmd == "hud")
        {
            p.Send(hud);
        }
        else if (cmd == "greenscreen")
        {
            p.Send(green);
        }
        else if (cmd == "regular")
        {
            p.Send(regular);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to execute config");
        cmd2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (cmd2 == "switch")
        {
            debug = !debug;
        }
        WebConfigReader conf = new WebConfigReader(url);
        string[] tokens = Regex.Split(conf.ReadString(), @"\r?\n|\r");
        foreach (string s in tokens)
        {
            p.Send(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make it so there will be an else if that checks for a different bool called "beta". How would you suggest I go about this? I have tried using a simple if else but it just doesn't work.

Comment: A `bool` is either true or false so the only way to do this would be to compare one with the other so for example `if ((debug) & !(beta))`

Comment: Example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yZBf3i)

Answer (score 0):

With 2 booleans, you have 4 different states. You could use:

```
if (debug && beta)
else if (debug && !beta)
else if (!debug && beta)
else
```

other small comment: With you cmd, I would have used the switch(cmd) statement.

Comment: Switch on strings is exactly the same as a bunch of string compares, though. Switch was originally designed because it was a very efficient low-level way of evaluating small numeric ranges. There's no real benefit to using a switch in this code. Heck, even for compacting, since they're all one-line statements, you can just leave off the brackets and it'll take less space than the switch structure would.

Comment: I once read that the compiler determines how to implement a switch depending on the number of case statements. If 7 or less if will build an if tree, otherwise it builds a dictionary with jump address or lambda's. Calculating the hash takes more time then doing a few compares. It may help to set the most frequent entries at the top. And a switch reads better.